# Node Memory Leak Causes setInterval Delay

Tags: node.js, postgresql, memory-leaks, setinterval

I'm trying to ID what's slowing down a DB connection.  I've narrowed it down to probably being a memory leak.  Following instructions in [this guide](https://www.alexkras.com/simple-guide-to-finding-a-javascript-memory-leak-in-node-js/), I've set up a heap profiling function to run at intervals throughout the program.  Essentially like this:

```
setInterval(function(){heapingFunction()},100);  
//some code

const pgClient = new pg.Client(dbConfig);
app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    logger.debug(err);
  } else {
    logger.info("listening at " + port + " port");
  }
});
pgClient.connect()
.then(function (connection) {
    logger.info("database connect");
    console.log("database connect");
    return pgClient.query("query");
})
.then(function (result) {Queries})
```

When I run this, instead of consistent heap snapshots at .1s intervals, I get a huge jump:

```
info: listening at 3001 port
Program is using 39904440 bytes of Heap.
Program is using 39927960 bytes of Heap.
Program is using 40055272 bytes of Heap.
Program is using 40086448 bytes of Heap.
info: database connect
database connect
Program is using 206523904 bytes of Heap.
Program is using 206546224 bytes of Heap.
Program is using 206665472 bytes of Heap.
Program is using 206874608 bytes of Heap.
Program is using 206929464 bytes of Heap.
```

It works as expected until the heap snapshot before `info: database connect`.  There, it stops until the DB connect (~5min).  As you can see, it's using 5x as much memory once it resumes (It's also much slower). It would be more useful to have snapshots during this time period, not just before and after.  What's going on here?  Is the memory leak so severe that setInterval can't even run?

Comment: What does `heapingFunction()` do?

Comment: @peteb It takes a heap snap shot and prints how many bytes are being used (as shown).  I've double-checked that this seems to be an issue with setInterval though, by replacing `heapingFunction()` with `console.log("Tick")`.  Both exhibit the same strange behavior.